# Google Cloud Messaging for Android sending message

Tags: cloud, message, google-cloud-messaging

I try to used GCM to send message to android. But I have a problem that, e.g. first, second and third message delivered to android and next messages not delivered. After cca X minutes again some messages are delivered and then not delivered. There is URL to call sending notification to GCM Server. Android device is still connected to internet (no sleep, no display off) Do I have a good parameters?

https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

and parameter:

```
String.Format("collapse_key={4}&time_to_live={3}&delay_while_idle=0&data.message={0}&data.time={1}&registration_id={2}", value, System.DateTime.Now, deviceId, timeToLive, DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

I receive from server response: id=0:123354....

Comment: **New commnet**
I sended 7 message succesfull in 10 minutes. Then 20 minutes i try to send next 10 message no deliveried. After 20 minutes again i try to send about 7 messages and these messages are delivered... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the order of delivery is not guaranteed. And it is not guaranteed to work with the new version of [code](http://application.developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html)
from my point of view i think google may block the messages if they are sent to quick.
like 10msgs in 2-3min.

Comment: What can be done to solve this issue? I would like to develop an instant messaging app using GCM. Any hints?